# Sorting objects based on Double values?

Tags: scala, comparison

Sorting objects is simple enough by mixing in Ordered and providing a compare() function, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131925/how-do-i-sort-an-array-in-scala). But what if your sorting value is a Double instead of an Int?

> def compare(that: MyClass) = this.x - that.x

where x is a Double will lead to a compiler error: "type mismatch; found: Double required: Int"

Is there a way to use Doubles for the comparison instead of casting to Ints?

Comment: This idiom is broken also for integer types, as it will produce wrong results on overflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way is to delegate to [`compare`](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/runtime/RichDouble.html#compare(Double)) implementation of `RichDouble` (to which your `Double` will be implicitly converted):

```
def compare(that : MyClass) = x.compare(that.x)
```

The advantage of this approach is that it works the same way for all primitive types.